# Extjs4 drag and drop grid after grid.removeAll()

Tags: drag-and-drop, grid, extjs4, removeall

I have two grid-panels to drag from `grid1` and drop on `grid2`, and a reset button with this handler function:

```
handler: function(){
                //refresh source grid
                Ext.getCmp('grid1').getStore().load();
                //purge destination grid
                Ext.getCmp('grid2').removeAll();
            }
```

All works good, but when I click on the reset button, I can't drop on `grid2` again!

Comment: may be try removing only the child nodes of root node will help, as drag n drop needs atleast one root node to drop into.

Comment: How to do it, sorry but I haven't understood you

Comment: while resetting you can remove only the records from the store of that grid, in this case removeAll on grid may cause a js error and thats why the drag no longer works. so for removal: Ext.getCmp('grid2').getStore().removeAll()

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `removeAll()` method from the grid component here, not the store... which probably breaks the grid.

You should try with:

```
Ext.getCmp('grid2').getStore().removeAll();
```